# .pde files as Java class files in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I set up Eclipse as a Processing IDE according to this article:  http://processing.org/learning/eclipse/  I've also associated .pde files with the Java editor.  However, .pde files are not being treated as class files, even if they are in the Java build path, and of the form:

`class MyNewSketch extends SomeClass {

...

}`

How do I get Eclipse's Java IDE to see .pde files as .java files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the file association for PDE files which you created. Instead expand the *Text/Java Source File* node on the *General -> Content Types* preference page. Add your `*.pde` content type to the already existing `*.java (locked)` content type and it works fine.

Comment: This worked great.  However, there is a gotcha that confused me.  Content Types may have on the top level 'Java Class File' with file association '*.class (locked)'. DO NOT add the *.pde there.  Instead, open 'Text' and add it to 'Java Source File' with file association '*.java (locked)'